# how to calculate video size from frame width and height

Tags: video, mp4, video-capture

How do I calculate the size of the video that has to be captured from the width and height of the frame?

For Example,

The video streaming resolution is 1920*1080 YUY2.

So the frame size will be 1920*1080*2 = 4147200 bytes(Approx 3.9MB).
But when capturing the video, the output size of the (.mp4) file is very low.

What could be the reason for this? Bitrate or compression?
Let me know the actual calculation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is compression. Video compression lossy, meaning you can drop bits, and therefor image quality. There is little relationship between resolution and file size. File size is determined by the bitrate. For example a 10 second 1080p video at 5mbps is 50mbps(10*5), a a 10 second 480p video at 5mbps is exactly the same 50mbps(10*5). But it will be higher quality because there are more bits per pixel. File size is a preference. There are no formulas for preferences.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts,

Answer (score 0):

I have finally done this by calculating the file size after writing every and every frame on the disk.